# Google Colab - Tensorflow model_main_tf2: Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, object-detection-api

I have been running this object detection model evaluation on google colab without errors. Now suddenly it does not work anymore but when running the script.

```
# RUN MODEL EVALUATION
PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH="./object_detection/checkpoints/detection/{}/pipeline.config".format(selected_model)
MODEL_DIR="./object_detection/checkpoints/detection/{}/checkpoint/".format(selected_model)
CHECKPOINT_DIR="./object_detection/checkpoints/detection/{}/checkpoint/".format(selected_model)

!python ./object_detection/model_main_tf2.py \
  --pipeline_config_path={PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
  --model_dir={MODEL_DIR} \
  --checkpoint_dir={CHECKPOINT_DIR} \
  --eval_timeout=5 \
  --alsologtostderr
```

It comes with the following errors:

```
I1112 16:05:22.433352 139759485175680 checkpoint_utils.py:149] Found new checkpoint at ./object_detection/checkpoints/detection/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8/checkpoint/ckpt-0
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py:401: UserWarning: `tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase` is deprecated and will be removed after 2020-10-11. To update it, simply pass a True/False value to the `training` argument of the `__call__` method of your layer or model.
  warnings.warn('`tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase` is deprecated and '
2021-11-12 16:05:22.520333: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:185] None of the MLIR Optimization Passes are enabled (registered 2)
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
I1112 16:05:31.542140 139759485175680 convolutional_keras_box_predictor.py:154] depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
I1112 16:05:31.542605 139759485175680 convolutional_keras_box_predictor.py:154] depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
I1112 16:05:31.542898 139759485175680 convolutional_keras_box_predictor.py:154] depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
I1112 16:05:31.543214 139759485175680 convolutional_keras_box_predictor.py:154] depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
I1112 16:05:31.543522 139759485175680 convolutional_keras_box_predictor.py:154] depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
INFO:tensorflow:depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
I1112 16:05:31.543864 139759485175680 convolutional_keras_box_predictor.py:154] depth of additional conv before box predictor: 0
2021-11-12 16:06:17.471428: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:362] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 8.0.5 but source was compiled with: 8.1.0.  CuDNN library needs to have matching major version and equal or higher minor version. If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified during compile configuration.
2021-11-12 16:06:17.474623: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:362] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 8.0.5 but source was compiled with: 8.1.0.  CuDNN library needs to have matching major version and equal or higher minor version. If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified during compile configuration.
INFO:tensorflow:Encountered 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unknown:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/Conv1/Conv2D (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_keras_feature_extractor.py:161) ]]
     [[Identity_18/_1166]]
  (1) Unknown:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/Conv1/Conv2D (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_keras_feature_extractor.py:161) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_compute_eval_dict_24301]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/Conv1/Conv2D:
 features_1 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:932)

Input Source operations connected to node ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/Conv1/Conv2D:
 features_1 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:932)

Function call stack:
compute_eval_dict -> compute_eval_dict
 exception.
I1112 16:06:19.558837 139759485175680 model_lib_v2.py:934] Encountered 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unknown:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/Conv1/Conv2D (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_keras_feature_extractor.py:161) ]]
     [[Identity_18/_1166]]
  (1) Unknown:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/Conv1/Conv2D (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/models/ssd_mobilenet_v2_keras_feature_extractor.py:161) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_compute_eval_dict_24301]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/Conv1/Conv2D:
 features_1 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:932)

Input Source operations connected to node ssd_mobile_net_v2keras_feature_extractor/model/Conv1/Conv2D:
 features_1 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py:932)

Function call stack:
compute_eval_dict -> compute_eval_dict
 exception.
INFO:tensorflow:A replica probably exhausted all examples. Skipping pending examples on other replicas.
I1112 16:06:19.559331 139759485175680 model_lib_v2.py:935] A replica probably exhausted all examples. Skipping pending examples on other replicas.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 115, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "./object_detection/model_main_tf2.py", line 90, in main
    wait_interval=300, timeout=FLAGS.eval_timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 1157, in eval_continuously
    global_step=global_step,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 1001, in eager_eval_loop
    for evaluator in evaluators:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

It was still working last week but for some reason not anymore. Anyone else struggling with this same problem? Some problems with Colab environment I guess but don't know what I should change.
TF2 object detection API installed and tested that it is working

```
Tensorflow 2.6.2
Found GPU at: /device:GPU:0
```

Comment: thinking about stop developing in Colab.  Running into too many of this unstable conditions which I do not have any control.  Very poor maintainence job by Colab.

Answer (score 2):

The error was occurring because of the wrong cuDNN version on Google Colab.

I was able to fix it by downloading the correct version of cuDNN from the NVidia developer site, and then installing it into Google Colab. I first copied the cuDNN package into my Google Colab notebook from Google Drive, and then installed it using the following:

```
!dpkg -i libcudnn8_8.1.0.77-1+cuda11.2_amd64.deb
# Check if package has been installed
!ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.*
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be deleted after some time?